# View not visible

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

My application starts with Root controller called `TaskController : UINavigationController`
as as root view controller of `UINavigationController` i created class `TaskRootController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate>` (it has add as view `UITableView`);
When I start application i see only Title form TaskRootController and background color from it.
But I don't see table view.
If my application starts with `TaskRootController` as a `rootViewController` I see table view.

How can I make to see table view in may case ?

**Edit**

```
 @implementation TaskRootController

@synthesize taskRootView; //table view

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"SIZE x:%f,y:%f ; %f:%f", self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.title = @"Root";
    self.taskRootView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.view addSubview:self.taskRootView];
    self.taskRootView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat result = 20.0f;
    if([tableView isEqual:self.taskRootView])
    {
        result = 40.0f;
    }
    return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: post your code.How you are setting rootViewController?

Comment: @PratyushaTerli: +1 for coming back!!!

Comment: If you have placed your table view in .xib. Then be sure to add table view delegate and data source to file owner.

Comment: paste your code which you had written in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions mehtod

Comment: @user1863111-check my edited :0

Comment: self.taskRoot = [[TaskController alloc] initWithNill.....] //initialization of controller
self.window.rootViewController = self.taskRoot;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Answer (score 0):

For Add `UITableView`

put delegate and datasource in `TaskRootController.h` file.

```
@interface TaskRootController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

And put this code in `TaskRootController.m` file

```
self.tblView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tblView.delegate = self;
    self.tblView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tblView];
```

And add relevant **delegate and datasource** method of `UITabelView`.

**EDIT:**

Check your below method .. add it proper or not ??

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1; // put number for section.
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 6; // put number as you want row in section.
}
```

Comment: I think those methods are not needed to diplay simple table view (white background with grey doted lines), because TaskRootController diplays everythink ok when I set it as root controller in my app (not root in my UINavigationController )

Answer (score 0):

@iPatel - I think those methods are not needed to display simple table view (white background with grey doted lines), because TaskRootController displays everything ok when I set it as root controller in my app (not root in my UINavigationController )

@Manohar - I doesn't have code within arm's reach. But as I remembered it looks like:

```
self.taskRoot = [[TaskController alloc] initWithNill.....] //initialization of controller
self.window.rootViewController = self.taskRoot; 
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```